# Ordering of files opened by program

Tags: bash, wildcards

When I open a set of files, usually just by using a glob character to open all the files in a directory or a subset, typically if not always the default is for the files to be opened by alphabetical sort. How do I get the files to be opened by, say, modification date, such as you might be able to see with an `ls -lt` command?

Comment: so it seems that `ls -1rt | xargs [name of program]` does what I want

Comment: You can do it in `zsh`, using the `(om)` / `(Om)` glob modifiers, I think

Comment: and of course `ls -rt ...` should work as well hehe

Comment: anything similar for `bash` @steeldriver??

Comment: Nothing equivalent in bash as far as I know, no

Answer (score 1):

Globs are expanded by the shell and in alphabetical order. To *see* that order, don't use `ls` as `ls` also sorts its list of arguments (though see the `-U` option in the GNU implementation to skip that sorting).

The only shell that lets you expand the globs in a different sort order is `zsh` with its `o` (and `O` for reverse) glob qualifier (and `n` for numeric ordering).

```
print -rC1 -- *(oL) # sort by length
print -rC1 -- *(om) # sort by modification time
print -rC1 -- *(n)  # numeric sort
print -rC1 -- *(o+myfunc) # sort lexically after transformation by myfunc
print -rC1 -- *(oe['some code']) # same with inline code
```

etc.